# Active resource post method unwanted returned value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeresource

Googled a lot but i did not find any solution for this problem.

I am using **activeresource** POST method to call a definition on the target application. The request is OK but the value which is returned is not what i want. The call method code is as:
**USER** is an activeresource model.

```
User.post(:method_name, {:params1 => "value1", :params2 => "value2"})
```

And on the target application i return the following:

```
{:message=>"Process successful"}
```

It works fine when i use GET instead of POST. But this is what i get which is wrong.

```
#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

Where is the problem..?

Comment: Is the target an open api that others can look at? If so it might be worth posting a link to that api.

Comment: @ScottJShea it is not an open api.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the response body via the `body` method, ie:

```
response = User.post(:method_name, {:params1 => "value1", :params2 => "value2"})
puts response.body
#=> "{:message=>"Process successful"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

After a severe RnD i found nothing to the above issue.. BUT i found one thing which helped me to some extent.

I used [filter_parameter_logging](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/filter_parameter_logging/class) to filter sensitive parameters.